# MaxScript: What 'callback type name' would be used to to trigger a callback when a node changes type/class?

Tags: types, callback, definition, 3dsmax, maxscript

My MaxScript tool requires a scene object to be of the type editable_mesh or editable_poly, and depending on the object type will enable and disable GUI controls.

Using the `#selectionSetChanged` callback I can have my rollout update successfully when the user changes the selected object, but if they convert an object they are forced to deselect it and select it again to operate on it.

What callback type name should I supply to callbacks.addscript, in order for it to be called when the user changes/converts the type/class of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the [Node Event System](http://gritengine.com/maxscript_html/node_event_system.htm) by calling NodeEventCallback and provided my function to the `modelstructured` property.

This operates a layer over the standard event callback system and has a number of new events, however it is only available for 3ds Max 2009 and above.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a callback event that I'm aware of, not even a when construct would work here. One way to accomplish that would be to use a timer in the rollout and on each tick check the class/superClass of the selected object/s but I'm not sure it's actually needed in the first place.

If you want to warn the user that the object needs to be converted, there are many ways to do it with his cooperation, like popping up a queryBox on select that would say something like *"Clicked object is not an Editable Mesh. Convert it to one?"* or a custom querybox with options *Convert to Editable Poly/Convert to Editable Mesh/Discard*.

Or even the old-fashioned way, having all the controls in question disabled by default, only a big Pick Node pickbutton enabled. That one would have been supplied with a filter function that would only let you pick editable node(s).

Comment: Thanks! Though after posting this one of the posters on the CGS forums acctually told me about a method, NodeEventCallback, which allows you to supply functions for specific events (above the original callbacks functionality). The modelstructured 'trigger' worked well for what I wanted to do.
Could I ask, what is a when construct? That sounds like something that may be useful with other problems.

Comment: Max 9 here, no NodeEventCallback to make use of, I'm sorry. The best explanation is in the maxscript reference, in the chapter Change Handlers and When Constructs. The basic syntax is `when  <topology | geometry | name[s] | transform | select | parameters | subAnimStructure | controller | children>  <objects> change[s] [ id:<name> ] \ [handleAt:#redrawViews|#timeChange] \ [ <object_parameter> ] do <expr>` and in contrast to callbacks you have to specify a certain node/nodes/collection (it can be for example $node, #($node1,$node2,$node3), $box*, selection, objects etc.).

Comment: Thanks for 'when' prototype. I didn't think of the version, if I upload my tool I'll probably write an alternative version with a pick button, or maybe rely on the user reading the ReadMe* to understand its behaviour.
(*It happens!....sometimes...maybe...right? ;))

Comment: Well, maybe it could happen if the number of users is big enough :) If you really want them to read it, make a "Don't push" button that will either shellLaunch notepad with the readme file open or show a textbox.

Comment: HA Very good! Though now I will *acctually* have to do that for one of my programs... :D